# How can I simplify an object iteration code?

Tags: javascript, object, iteration

Having the next object:

```
2018: {
    01: {
         01: { key: value }
         02: { key: value }
         03: { key: value }
        },
    02: { ...  }
    },
2019: {
    01: ...
```

How can I simplify the next code used for getting the values into each day object?

```
   for (let yearIndex in obj) {
      const year = obj[yearIndex]
      for (let monthIndex in year) {
        const month = year[monthIndex]
        for (let dayIndex in month) {
          const day = month[dayIndex] {
              console.log(day)
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The ideal result may be an array with the object of each day:

```
[{ key: value }, { key: value }, ...]
```

Comment: I think this question is more suited for [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: `Object.entries(obj).map(([yearIndex, year]) => Object.entries(year).map(([monthIndex, month]) => ...` could also simply further with `Object.values` if you don't care about indicies.

Comment: @mhodges asking how to shorten/simplify code is on topic for SO...

Comment: btw, what is `response.val()` retuning?

Comment: What's that `.val()` method? Don't call it multiple times.

Comment: @JaredSmith Just said "more suited for". I didn't vote to close or downvote.

Comment: What are you actually doing with the `day` values, is logging them the only thing? Do you need the `…Index` values for anything?

Comment: Hi folks, I removed the `response.val()` method. It is a Firebase functions that returns the object.

Comment: What does simplify mean? Are you asking to reduce the number of loops or the number of lines of code?

Comment: @frederickf exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could flat the objects by checking the type for a recursive call.

```js
function getFlat(object) {
    return [].concat(
        ...Object
            .values(object)
            .map(value => value && typeof value === 'object' ? getFlat(value) : object)
    );
}

var object = {2018: { '01': { '01': { key: 1 }, '02': { key: 2 }, '03': { key: 3 } }, '02': { '01': { key: 4 }, '02': { key: 5 }, '03': { key: 6 } } }, 2019: { '01': { '01': { key: 7 }, '02': { key: 8 }, '03': { key: 9 } } } };

console.log(getFlat(object));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to get the leaves of a tree (in other words, the values that are not themselves objects), you can make a simple recursive function. This works especially well when you don't know exactly how deep the nesting will be.

This will look at each value and if it's an object pass it back through. Otherwise it will push it to an array:

```js
let obj = {2018: {'01': { 01: 'test18_11', 02: 'test18_12', 03: 'test18_13',},'02': { 01: 'test18_21', 02: 'test18_22', 03: 'test18_23',}},2019: {'01': { 01: 'test19_11', 02: 'test19_12', 03: 'test19_13', },'02': { 01: 'test19_21', 02: 'test19_22', 03: 'test19_23',}}}

function recurse(obj, a = []) {
    Object.values(obj).forEach(value => {
        if (typeof value === 'object') return recurse(value, a)
        else  a.push(value)
    })
    return a
}

console.log(recurse(obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
  2018: {
    01: {
      01: '01 first',
      02: '01 second',
    },
    02: {
      01: '02 first'
    }
  },
  2019: {
    01: {}
  }
};

Object.values(obj).forEach(year => {
  Object.values(year).forEach(month => {
    Object.values(month).forEach(day => {
      console.log(day);
    })
  })
})
```